# NoSuchMethodError: The getter "name" was called on null

Tags: flutter

The code below searches for the carpark in the database where the user is present.  If one cannot be found (i.e. the user is not located near any carparks in the database), set it to a carpark 'Home'.  However, the following error occurs:

[image]

It appears that the following code is not working:
[image]

Pls help.  Thank you very much.

```
String currentScreen = 'myLocation';
double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;

class MyLocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = '/myLocationScreen';
  @override
  _MyLocationScreenState createState() => _MyLocationScreenState();
}

class _MyLocationScreenState extends State<MyLocationScreen> {
  List<Carpark> carparkList = []; //List for storing carparks
  Carpark nearbyCarpark;
  LocationData _currentPosition;
  GoogleMapController mapController;

  Location location = Location();

  GoogleMapController _controller;
  LatLng _initialcameraposition = LatLng(22.35278, 114.18527);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future readFromFirebase2() async {
    print('reading from Firebase');
    Carpark _thisCarpark;
    List<Carpark> _carparkList = [];
    Provider.of<CarparksProvider>(context, listen: false).clearCarparks();

    // await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('carpark')
        .orderBy('region')
        .orderBy('district')
        .orderBy('name')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {


      snapshot.docs.forEach(
        (DocumentSnapshot cp) {
          _thisCarpark = Carpark(
            cp.get('name'),
            cp.get('region'),
            cp.get('district'),
            cp.get('lat'),
            cp.get('long'),
            cp.get('fee1'),
            cp.get('fee2'),
            cp.get('remark'),
            cp.get('url'),
          );

          Provider.of<CarparksProvider>(context, listen: false)
              .addCarpark(_thisCarpark);
        },
      );

      _carparkList =
          Provider.of<CarparksProvider>(context, listen: false).carparks;

      _carparkList.forEach((carpark) {
      });
    });
    carparkList = _carparkList;
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController _cntlr) {
    _controller = _cntlr;
    location.onLocationChanged.listen((l) {
      _controller.animateCamera(
        CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
          CameraPosition(target: LatLng(l.latitude, l.longitude), zoom: 15),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  double distanceBetween(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    double distance =
        pow((pow((x1 - x2), 2.0) + pow((y1 - y2), 2.0)), 0.5) * 100.0;
    print('distance: ' + distance.toStringAsFixed(1) + 'km');
    return distance;
  }

  void getCurrentCarpark() {
    Carpark _nearbyCarpark;

    for (Carpark cp in carparkList) {
      print(cp.name);
      if (distanceBetween(cp.lat, cp.long, latitude, longitude) < 1) {
        // distance within 1km
        _nearbyCarpark = cp;
      }
    }

    if (_nearbyCarpark = null) {
      //If the current location is one of the carparks in the database, set 'Home' as the current carpark

      _nearbyCarpark =
          carparkList.firstWhere((carpark) => carpark.name == 'Home');

    }
    nearbyCarpark = _nearbyCarpark;
  }

  void getCurrentLoc() async {
    bool _serviceEnabled;
    PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;

    _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }

    _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }

    _currentPosition = await location.getLocation();
    latitude = _currentPosition.latitude;
    longitude = _currentPosition.longitude;

    print(latitude);
    print(longitude);

    _initialcameraposition =
        LatLng(_currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);
    location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
       setState(() {
        _currentPosition = currentLocation;
        _initialcameraposition =
            LatLng(_currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);
      });
    });
  }

  Future<void> initialisation() async {
    await readFromFirebase2();
    getCurrentLoc();
    getCurrentCarpark();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    initialisation();
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: readFromFirebase2(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: GoogleMap(
                      initialCameraPosition:
                          CameraPosition(target: _initialcameraposition),
                      mapType: MapType.normal,
                      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                      myLocationEnabled: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  nearbyCarpark.name,
                  style: knearbyCarparkTextStyle,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 200,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                    // Code for link to current carpark
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Car park Fee',
                      style: kCarparkTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have double-checked and all elements are not null......

Comment: make sure you use _nearbyCarpark != null not _nearbyCarpark = null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the whole codesnippet

```
if (_nearbyCarpark = null) {
  //If the current location is one of the carparks in the database, set 'Home' as the current carpark

  _nearbyCarpark =
      carparkList.firstWhere((carpark) => carpark.name == 'Home');

}
nearbyCarpark = _nearbyCarpark;
```

the error, the error is in the condition (it's quite subtle):

```
if (_nearbyCarpark = null)
```

is an assignment (`=`) and not a comparison (which would be `==`). So I'm wondering how this is even compiling (I'm not that experienced with Dart, bit I'm pretty sure, when doing `if (condition)`, the `condition` has to be a `bool`). If it does indeed compile it would be equivalent to

```
if (null) {
...
}
```

which probably wouldn't even execute the body. Also, remember you set `_nearbyCarpark` to `null` within the condition, so when you are setting

```
nearbyCarpark = _nearbyCarpark
```

after the `if`, there is probably some data-binding going nuts, because you set its datasource to `null` ...

So you probably need to do

```
if (_nearbyCarpark == null)
```

instead